# Regex - locate first ')' after matching string

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I am doing a mass method replace in my C# codebase. I have lines of code that look like the following:

```
Assert.That(Edit.FundsTable.GetCellByIndexes(0, 2).Text.Contains("Employer Request IPM A"));
```

The problem is that initially when the GetCellByIndexes call was made, we had another method that basically did the same thing, leaving us doing the exact same task 2 ways. The more standard way that we are changing it to is the following:

```
Assert.That(Edit.FundsTable.Cells[0, 2].Text.Contains("Employer Request IPM A"));
```

I am trying to do a VS replace all replacement to move GetCellByIndexes calls to Cells calls. The issue is with the right paran. I can do a replace all from

```
GetCellByIndexes(
```

to

```
Cells[
```

very easily. The problem is changing the right paran of the method call to a square bracket. Does anyone know how to identify the first right paran after the "GetCellByIndexes" string utilizing Regex?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio find and replace feature? Or are you coding in C#?

Comment: Visual Studio's find and replace feature.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```cs
GetCellByIndexes\(([^()]+)\)
```

Replace with `Cells[$1]`. See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/GcSV7B/1).

| Code | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| GetCellByIndexes | 'GetCellByIndexes' |
| `\(` | '(' |
| `(` | group and capture to $1: |
| `[^()]+` | any character except: '(', ')' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of $1 |
| `\)` | ')' |

Answer (score 0):

In general search for:

```
GetCellByIndexes\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)
```

replace with

```
Cells[$1, $2]
```

Both if you are using the search-and-replace of Visual Studio or if you are programming in C#.

Note that this will only work if the indexes are numbers... If they are something more complex (variables, or functions) then it becomes more interesting (and complex).